# Notepad++ doesn't highlight the attribute autofocus

Tags: html, notepad++

Notepad++ does not highlight `autofocus` as red like it does to the others attributes.

[image: Image of code with autofocus not highlighted]

Is that the intended behavior, am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug?
I don't suppose it's possible to just add the keyword myself, right?
Let me know if there's anyway to fix this problem.

Comment: it will show like that only

Comment: Does it also happens to you @Edison?

Comment: Hello, it is normal for the default style configurator. If you go to -> settings -> style configurator -> and select the theme i.e. Bespin. you will se it highlighted. Of course you can check other themes and select the one you like most.

Comment: @J.Vie yes in notepad++ autofocus  will show as black only

Comment: I changed the style and some of them did highlighted the word, @SergeInácio. Is it not considered an attribute?

Comment: @J. Vie it is called an ATRIBUTEUNKNOWN, you can change the color in the style configurator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notepad++ has its own idea of the syntax of HTML. This may vary by Notepad++ version; the current version (7.3.2) does not seem to recognize `contenteditable` and `spellcheck` either – they are, like `autofocus`, shown in the settings for `ATTRIBUTEUNKNOWN`. If you like, you can use the Style Configurator (in the Settings menu) to set that rendering to the same as for `ATTRIBUTE`, but then you would also see e.g. attributes `conteteditable` and `foobar` in that color, too.

There does not seem to be any way to change the set of recognized attributes except by editing the source of Notepad++. In the Language menu, there is the option “Define your language”, but it is far from obvious how to use it to define your own version of HTML. It seems that the formalisms used are limited, since Notepad++ seems to show e.g. the tag `<action>` in the color for recognized tags, probably because `action` is a valid *attribute* name and the Notepad++ definitions for HTML have a list of keywords, including both tag and attribute names.

So don’t take the syntax highlighting and coloring in Notepad++ too seriously. It usually helps, but it’s far from perfect and should not be taken as a criterion for syntactic correctness.